# If condition not triggering

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an if statement that checks if a variable is true or false and binds a mousewheel event, and i have a scroll event that sets that variable to true. The problem is, my if condition is only trigered on load, not when the value changes to true.

Code example inside controller:

```
$scope.first = angular.element(document.querySelector('#first'));
$scope.second = angular.element(document.querySelector('#second'));

$scope.firstActive = true;
$scope.secondActive = false;

angular.element($window).bind("scroll", function () {
        var scrollTop = angular.element($window).scrollTop();
        var firstO = $scope.first.offset().top;
        var secondO = $scope.second.offset().top;

        var firstDistance = (scrollTop - firstO);
        var secondDistance = (scrollTop - secondO);

        if (firstDistance < 600) {
            $scope.firstActive = true;
            $scope.secondActive = false;             
        }

        if (secondDistance >= 0) {
            $scope.firstActive = false;
            $scope.secondActive = true;                
        }
});

if ($scope.secondActive) {
        html.css('overflowY', 'hidden');
        whatIDo.css('display', 'block');

        angular.element(whatIDo).bind("mousewheel", function (e) {
            if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta < 0) {
                //scroll down
                console.log('Down');
                $scope.secondSlide = true;
                $scope.firstSlide = false;
                whatIDo.css('display', 'none');
                html.css('overflowY', 'auto');

            } else {
                //scroll up
                console.log('Up');
                $scope.secondSlide = false;
                $scope.firstSlide = true;
                whatIDo.css('display', 'none');
                html.css('overflowY', 'auto');

            }
            $scope.$apply();
        });
    }
```

What I want to achieve is to trigger mousewheel on an overlay and switch content (first slide and second slide), then continue to scroll page. But, my if statement is not triggering even though the variable is set to true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like there's anything in your code that will trigger that `if` statement, and the statement itself has no way of knowing when your `secondActive` property has been updated. I think what you want is [$scope.$watch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch):

> Registers a listener callback to be executed whenever the watchExpression changes.

```
$scope.$watch('secondActive', function() {
  alert('Now I can do whatever I want when the variable changes!');
  // Put your if statement here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Create one **method** which contains `if condition code` and call from `onload` as well as from `event listener`.

```
$scope.first = angular.element(document.querySelector('#first'));
$scope.second = angular.element(document.querySelector('#second'));

$scope.firstActive = true;
$scope.secondActive = false;

angular.element($window).bind("scroll", function () {
        var scrollTop = angular.element($window).scrollTop();
        var firstO = $scope.first.offset().top;
        var secondO = $scope.second.offset().top;

        var firstDistance = (scrollTop - firstO);
        var secondDistance = (scrollTop - secondO);

        if (firstDistance < 600) {
            $scope.firstActive = true;
            $scope.secondActive = false;             
        }

        if (secondDistance >= 0) {
            $scope.firstActive = false;
            $scope.secondActive = true;                
        }
       onChange();  // call on event
});

function onChange(){
       if ($scope.secondActive) {
        html.css('overflowY', 'hidden');
        whatIDo.css('display', 'block');

        angular.element(whatIDo).bind("mousewheel", function (e) {
            if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta < 0) {
                //scroll down
                console.log('Down');
                $scope.secondSlide = true;
                $scope.firstSlide = false;
                whatIDo.css('display', 'none');
                html.css('overflowY', 'auto');

            } else {
                //scroll up
                console.log('Up');
                $scope.secondSlide = false;
                $scope.firstSlide = true;
                whatIDo.css('display', 'none');
                html.css('overflowY', 'auto');

            }
            $scope.$apply();
        });
    }
}
onChange(); // call on load
```